# How to compute roots of a polynomial in a list?

Tags: python, list

I'm having some troubles with a homework from my university, so I decided to post here for help

I have to create a list for polynomials. This part is okay:

```
n = int(input("Degree of polynomial: "))
p = []

for i in range(n+1):
    p.append(float(input("p["+str(i)+"]: ")))
    i += 1
```

For example, the polynomial:

```
                                             5x^4+3x^3-2x^2+x-2
```

Has:

```
                                                  n = 4
```

And the list indicated by:

```
                                             p[] = [5, 3, -2, 1, -2]
```

Also, I created a list with values that pretend to be roots of a polynomial (listPRoots, the possible roots). This part is also okay:

```
listPRoots= []

for i in range(int(p[0])): 
    if p[0]%(i+1) == 0:
        listPRoots.append(-(i+1))
        listPRoots.append(i+1)
```

As the code show, I have a list with the values that can be the roots of my polynomial. I used the rational roots theorem to make this list.

Now, I want to take a polynomial with coeficients in a list (p). With this polynomial, I want to verify every value inside the list (called listPRoots) to find the values of the roots of the polynomial. When I find this value, I want to put they in a new list (called listIntegrerRoots). For this, I tried:

```
listIntegrerRoots = []
listTestRoots     = []

for i in range(len(listPRoots) - 1):
    flag = len (p) - 1
    while flag > 0:
        root = (listPRoots[i]**(flag)) * p[flag]
        listTestRoots.append(root)
        flag = flag- 1
    if sum(listTestRoots)  + p[0] == 0:
        listIntegrerRoots.append(listPRoots[i])
```

But, I can't get the list I want. For example:

```
n = 2
p[0] = 6, p[1] = -5, p[2] = 1
```

result in:

```
x^2 - 5x + 6
```

and:

```
listPRoots[] = [-1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -6, 6]
```

I would:

```
listIntegrerRoots[] = [2, 3]
```

Because 2 and 3 are the roots of my polynomial. But I get:

```
listIntegrerRoots[] = []
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your posted code fails at the first `for` because `p` is undefined.  The value you post later is not included in the code, is not syntactically legal, describes a set rather than a list, and is not consistent with the polynomial coefficients just above.

Comment: It's confusing enough that you're mixing an English post with Portuguese (?) variable names, but it gets worse if you misspell them in your text - please use English examples as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't froget to clear your sum buffer `listTestRoots` every time you test a new possible root value.

Should be something like:

```
for i in range(len(listPRoots) - 1):
    listTestRoots = []
    ....
```

And from my point of view, an accumulative sum variable could be a better choice.

-- * Edit * --

```
In [23]: for i in range(len(listPRoots)):
    ...:     s = 0
    ...:     for j in range(len(p)):
    ...:         s += (listPRoots[i] ** j) * p[j]
    ...:     if s == 0:
    ...:         listIntegerRoots.append(listPRoots[i])
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:

In [24]: listIntegerRoots
Out[24]: [2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm a student of engineer, and I really don't know that 'accumaltive sum variable' means. Can you give me an example, please? And thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: Edited and you can have a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pacient and help!